# Action property of chrome desktop notification not working

Tags: jquery, notifications

I'm using notification.js for desktop notifications and I have used action property to give two actions: accept and reject. When I click on the notification area it works but when clicking accept or reject the click event is not firing...

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/act1oo0a/2/)

```
$('.b-icon-one').click(function () {
    var options = {
        iconUrl: '//github.com/favicon.ico',
        title: 'Only one! sss',
        tag: 'notificationReplaceId',
        body: Math.random(),
        actions: [{ action: 'Accept', title: "Accept" }, { action: 'Reject', title: "Reject" }]

    };

  $.notification(options);


});


function Accept()
{
    alert('Accept');
}

function Reject()
{

    alert('Reject');
}
```